# Why do I get a "string index out of range" error with letter variable above while word: statement but not below?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Below is some code from a game I am creating which scrambles the letters of a random word for a player to guess. I was wondering why when I put my letter variable (which assigns a random letter from one of the words in my word bank to the variable letter) above my `while word:` statement there is a string index error but if I put the same variable in the while word: statement there is no error.

I know that in the string `koala`, for example, `k` is `0` and `a` is `4`. Why would that change within the while statement? Or is there something else going on?

This works:

```
 while word:
     letter = random.randrange(len(word))
     scrambled_word += word[letter]
     word = word[:letter] + word[(letter+1):]
```

This does not work:

```
 scrambled_word = ''
 letter = random.randrange(len(word))

 while word:
     scrambled_word += word[letter]
     word = word[:letter] + word[(letter+1):]
```

Why?

Comment: Could you please show us a Traceback of where this is going wrong. THanks!

Comment: Welcome to Word Scramble 2.0!

The instructions are simple...

You will be given 5 chances to unscramble a word for
           a total of 7 points. Every guess after the first will
           cost you 1 point. You may also ask for a hint but
           it's going to cost you 2 points.

Good luck!


Hit enter to get your first word!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Walter/Documents/Python For Beginners/Chapter 4/word_scramble_2.py", line 28, in <module>
    scrambled_word += word[letter]
IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: @brabbit274... Next time please copy the *traceback* (i.e. starting from `Traceback (most ...)`) into your *question*, formatted as *code*. Otherwise it's quite unreadable.

Comment: I hope this is what you need. Like I said, I am extremely new so layman's terms would be a great help. Thank you for looking at the problem James!

Comment: @Bakuriu, ok will do! -Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Walter/Documents/Python For Beginners/Chapter 4/word_scramble_2.py", line 28, in <module>
    scrambled_word += word[letter]
IndexError: string index out of range

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With each iteration of

```
while word:
    scrambled_word += word[letter]
    word = word[:letter] + word[(letter+1):]
```

`word` is shortened by one letter:

```
>>> "koala"[:3]
'koa'
>>> "koala"[4:]
'a'
```

so eventually `word[letter]` will try to access a letter that's no longer there.

If you want to scramble a word, there's a built-in function for that, though:

```
>>> word = "koala"
>>> l = list(word)
>>> random.shuffle(l)
>>> word = "".join(l)
>>> word
'oklaa'
```

(taking a detour via a list object because strings themselves are immutable and can't be shuffled directly).

Comment: hm, but that's what I want. I want to add a random letter to the scrambled_word string until there are no more letters and the while statement loop will close?

Comment: OK, then you need to choose a new `letter` in each iteration, making sure that the parameter you're passing to `randrange()` is reduced by one each time.

Comment: a ha! now I understand! I "need to choose a new letter in each iteration". I get it now! Thank you Tim Pietzcker!

Answer (score -2):

I'm not a python programmer, but this is probably wrong:

```
word = word[:letter] + word[(letter+1):]
```

You need to check if the letter is the last one, otherwise `word[(letter+1):]` is out of bound.

Comment: If you're not a Python Programmer, then why answer?

    >>> xs = list(range(10))
    >>> xs[:10]
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    >>> xs[(10 + 1):]
    []

Comment: From the Python [string](http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/strings.html) documentation: _Degenerate slice indices are handled gracefully: an index that is too large is replaced by the string size_

Comment: Because the logic of algorythmisation is the same in all Level 3 programming languages. Of course some compilers/interpreters do add their own functions on top, but that does not change what is happening.

Comment: You should either test your answer before posting it or know Python very well. Your answer/statement(s) were wrong. See my baldy formatted interactive REPL session above.

Comment: Almost all languages allow the starting index of substring to be the length of the string, returning an empty string.

Comment: Or an empty list in my case.